# Protection from an asbestos wall

Tags: asbestos, backyard

The trapezoid-shaped wall in the back of the picture is a wall that my neighbor built between his backyard and mine:

[image]

Apparently, it is made from asbestos, which might be unhealthy.

In order to protect my family from potential health issues, I thought of painting the side facing my yard with an acryllic paint (my neighbor will probably not mind). Is this indeed a sufficient protection?

Alternatively, I thought of just buying a large plastic sheet and hang it over the asbestos wall. Will this provide enough protection?

Comment: "Apparently, it is made from asbestos" what makes you say that? What leads you to believe it is made from asbestos? Asbestos is not harmful/dangerous. It becomes harmful when you cut that fence and breath in the dust, if you don't make dust, it is safe.

Comment: When asbestos was used over 50 years ago it was not cheap ( like cement) and so, was not randomly used in construction.

Answer (score 4):

Paint is the best way to encapsulate asbestos, 
I am trying to figure out what part you believe is asbestos. The fence looks to have a metal roofing or siding, the wall in the back of the photo looks like corrugated fiberglass,  if corrugated fiberglass  I would not paint it without permission as it may be letting light in (we do this in our barns, The fiberglass allows light in but stops the wind and rain, if you paint it without permission you may be forced into replacing it. 
First I would want to identify what it is, I don’t remember any corrugated asbestos panels but could be wrong. If it is asbestos a quality exterior paint should be used (with permission) to encapsulate the material. A close up photo would help and if there is light that shines through at night it is not any kind of asbestos I have seen but probably fiberglass clear fiberglass yellows and has the little string looking hairs once it ages and this is what I think you have if you are talking about that surface and not the fence to the right.

Comment: Corrugated asbestos sheets were common until about 50 years ago, mostly for roofing, but they are completely opaque, and usually a stone-grey color unless they have a colored coating on them, since they're an asbestos strand-reinforced cement. As you say, these look yellowy, and translucent, so I'd agree with the likelihood that these are a fiberglass epoxy.